# How to split a string based on a word?

Tags: java, spring

I have a string in the below format

```
abc.xyz.*.*.{placeholder}
```

represents one or more words.
I want the substring without `{placeholder}` in a separate string. i.e 
`abc.xyz.`.

Can anyone please let me know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use regex.

```
String newString = myString.split("\{placeholder\}")[0];
```

will return the first part

Read this: [Java.lang.String.split() Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_split.htm)